# unable to resolve module image react native

Tags: react-native

I try to add image in my RN app by typing :

```
render()
{
return (
 <View style ={styles.container}>
    <Image source= {require('/home/app/app/components/images/ff.png')}  style = {{height: 200, width: 250, resizeMode : 'stretch',}} />
```

But i get this error

[image]

I tried to use `./ff.png` but i get the same error.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Image source= {require('./images/ff.png')}  style = {{height: 200, width: 250, resizeMode : 'stretch'}} />
```

It looks like it's the correct path.